# Intermediate subfields of $k(x)/k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $k(x)$ be the rational function field of one variable over a field $k$.
Are there infinitely many intermediate subfields of $k(x)/k$?

The motivation is as follows.
Dedekind wrote in his supplement to Dirichlet's Lecture on Number Theory as follows.

> Let $K$, $L$ be subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $K \subset L$.
>   If $L/K$ is a finite extension, it is easy to see by Galois theory that there are only finitely many intermidiate subfields of it. The converse is also true.

I tried to prove this. If $L/K$ is an infinite dimensional algebraic extension, it is easy to see that there are infinitely many intermidiate subfields.
So the question is reduced to: Are there infinitely many intermidiate subfields if $L/K$ is not algebraic?

Comment: This question should be re-opened: as the questioner observes, it is not so easy to _prove_ that the obvious-appearing things are true, I think. Sure, it is _possible_ (my algebra notes do such things), but in my experience the supposed obviousness is dismissed incompetently in too many sources... E.g., computation of the Galois group of $k(x)$ over $k(x^n)$ (with $n$th roots of unity in $k$)? Sure, it is do-able, but ... something is required.

Answer (score 2):

For any integer $k\gt 1$, consider the rational functions of $x^k$.

Comment: How do you prove that they are mutually different subfields?

Comment: The polynomial of smallest positive degree has degree $k$. Note that have shown the fields are *different.* They may be isomorphic.  We can get an infinite chain of proper subfields by looking at the rational functions in $x^{2^k}$.

Comment: *The polynomial of smallest positive degree has degree k.*
How do you prove this?

Comment: The polynomial of the form $f(x^k)$ are of the shape $a_0+a_1x^k+a_2x^{2k}+a_3x^{3k}+\cdots$ (finite sum).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the proof. Please elaborate so that any more questions would not be necessary.

Comment: Let $F$ be a field. You are interested in showing that the field $F(x)$ of formal rational functions (the quotient field of the ring $F[x]$ of polynomials) has infinitely many different subfields that contain $F$. Let $F_k(x)$ be the quotient field of the ring of polynomials of the form $P(x^k)$, where $k\ge 2$. Then $F_k(x)$ is a field, and if $k\ne l$ then $F_k(x)\ne F_l(x)$. For the polynomial of least degree $\gt 0$ in $F_k(x)$ has degree $k$, and the polynomial of least degree $\gt 0$ in $F_l(x)$ has degree $l$.